# How to Itterate Name of files and attache them to file content

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I want to have my data in this format

name of file: File contents

but when I run my code it does not work. Can you please help?

This grabs the names of the file

```
def list_of_files():
    path = '/mnt/c/baseline'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    for f in files:
        # print(f)
        return(files)
```

This loads the content

```
def load_file(filename):
    loadfile = open("aivc-tests/baseline/"+ filename, "r")
        return(loadfile)
```

This should get each file name and attach it to the correct loaded file

```
a = str(list_of_files())


data2 = []
data2 = { 
    for i in a:
        name_of_file: load_file(filename) 
}

print(data2)
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete the parantheses around the return values in the functions.

And then

```
loadfile = open("aivc-tests/baseline/"+ filename, "r")
```

only returns a kind of filepointer. You still need to call the `read()` function to get the Content of the file.
Change it to

```
def load_file(filename):
    # variable for file content
    text_str=""

    # open file
    with open("aivc-tests/baseline/"+ filename, "r") as f:

        # read file
        text_str=f.read()

    return text_str
```

Comment: and there is a mistake in your main code ``a = str(list_of_files())`` is wrong. You cast a to string. And you can`t properly iterate over a. Just leave it to ``a = list_of_files()``

Comment: Thank you I am fairly new to python here I am grateful

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code and made it run with some files I had on my computer. Of course this may differ with you since I don't know what type of file you are trying to open and what kind of data you are dealing with (numbers or strings).

Nevertheless, here is how I managed to make it work, I hope it helps:

```
def list_of_files():
    path = '/mnt/c/baseline'
    
    files = os.listdir(path)
        
    return(files)


def load_file(filename):
    loadfile = open("aivc-tests/baseline/"+ filename, "r")
    return(loadfile)


a = list_of_files()

data2 = { i : load_file(filename) for i in a } #dictionary with data and filenames
```

I also assume you may want to change the way you call "load_file(filename)" with "load_file(i)" to get the data of that exact file since "i" will be the string name of the file